# NSMenu.popUp(positioning:at:in:) doesn't enable menu items when opened inside modal window

Tags: cocoa, appkit

In my app I use `NSMenu.popUp(positioning:at:in:)` for displaying a menu in response to the user clicking a button.

But it seems that when the menu is opened inside a modal window, all the menu items are always disabled.

[image]

Using `NSMenu.popUpContextMenu(_:with:for:)` instead works. What's the reason and what's the difference between the two methods? According to the documentation, one is for opening "popup menus" and the other for opening "context menus", but I cannot see an explanation of the difference between the two.

```
@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let window = NSWindow(contentViewController: ViewController())
        NSApp.runModal(for: window)
    }

}

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        let button = NSButton(title: "Click", target: self, action: #selector(click(_:)))
        view = NSView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
    
    @objc func click(_ sender: Any?) {
        let menu = NSMenu(title: "")
        menu.addItem(withTitle: "asdf", action: #selector(asdf(_:)), keyEquivalent: "")
        menu.addItem(withTitle: "bla", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
        menu.items[0].target = self
        menu.items[1].target = self
//        NSMenu.popUpContextMenu(menu, with: NSApp.currentEvent!, for: view) // this works
        menu.popUp(positioning: nil, at: .zero, in: view) // this doesn't work
    }
    
    @IBAction func asdf(_ sender: Any) {
        print(0)
    }

}
```

Comment: From the release notes: "**NSMenu popUpMenuPositioningItem: atLocation: inView:** NSMenu has a new method for popping up a menu as if it were a popup button. This is meant to be an replacement for the Carbon function PopUpMenuSelect().". What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to show a menu below a button as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Can't you use `popUpContextMenu` or `NSPopUpButton` in pull-down mode?

Comment: Hacky undocumented possible workaround: implement `@objc func worksWhenModal() -> Bool` in `ViewController` and return `true`.

Comment: @Willeke Do you mean in `NSWindow`? I tried, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I mean in the `ViewController` class in the question.

Comment: `NSViewController` doesn't have `worksWhenModal`.

Comment: No, that's why `worksWhenModal` can be added without `override` and that's why the workaround is a hack.

Comment: Another possible workaround: don't set the target of the menu item.

Comment: I see, but adding an "arbitrary" method without even an override is really too much of a hack for my taste. Don't setting the target seems to work, oddly.